# Data extraction from an image using python and Pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I have an image that contains a table and I am trying to extract data from it and for this process I am using pytesseract as an OCR to help me read data from the image. My problem is that if the rows contain only a single line value in a cell then after reading the data I am able to split at '\n\n' and able to differentiate  the data into multiple rows but when I have multiple line values in single cell then I am not able to differentiate  what data belongs to which row.

The process I tried is as follows. The input image:

[image: vertical table image]

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

im = Image.open(r'verticaltable.png')
text = image_to_string(im)
print(text)
```

The output of the program

```
COLUMN A COLUMN B COLUMN C COLUMN D COLUMN E
1 Prime Minister Rule Country By people 5 years

and president
2 Civil officer Talented people Exam 25-60 years
3 Administrative Documents -

officers maintained
4 Law enforcement | Law Exam 25-60 years
```

I would like to achieve the output according to the columns(how to extract data going through the columns)

```
COLUMN A, 1, 2, 3,4
COLUMN B, Prime Minister and president Prime Minister and president,Civil officer,Administrative officers, Law enforcement 
COLUMN C, Rule Country,Talented people,Documents maintained,Law
COLUMN D ,By people,Exam,,Exam
COLUMN E, 5 years,25-60 years,-,25-60 years
```

Note:
I have already gone through this answer and have tired it but still its not working so kindly dont tag this link [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370642/how-to-extract-text-from-table-in-image)

Comment: Here's an alternate way to look at this problem: instead of one image, you have 25 small images. So you might approach this by: (1) finding lines with something like the Hough transform, (2) [detecting intersections of those lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565975/find-intersection-point-of-two-lines-drawn-using-houghlines-opencv), then (3) applying OCR on the 25 sub images.